# Getting frozen account when trying to transfer NFT for created ATA

Tags: web3.js, token, associated-token-account

Im getting frozen account when trying to transfer some NFTs from a recently created ATA:

I create the ATA in the same transaction that im sending the NFT for , and getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now there are a number of reason why you could be experiencing this:

1. It could be a restriction by the program for a certain amount of time after an account have being created that's freezing your transfer.
2. Could also mean you don't have enough SPL to pay for the transaction fee.

Comment: Is this a custom transaction for a program you wrote or are you doing a transfer using Phantom wallet?